# Service architecture for my app

Tags: android, service

I have an app that traces the location of the phone by using locationlistener to create breadcrumbs.  The user can start the app, then start breadcrumb trail recording.  The trail shows on a google map in the app live as the trip records.  The breadcrumbs are also sent to a clout database where other applications can access the trip being taken.

The user can end the app but choose to keep the breadcrumb recording going so other apps can still follow the trail real time.  If the user never comes back to stop recording, the recording will stop 24 hours from the time it started.  The user can, however, start the app anytime and stop recording of the trail.

It seems that my app should consist of an activity and a service that the activity binds to.  No other app will use this service so it seems the service should not have to be an IPC service.  The service does all of the location listening and logging to the cloud database.

My problem is that in the CommonsWare book on page 1226 it says that if my app calls unbindService(), android will shut down the service.  I want it to keep going until the activity shuts it down or it shuts itself down after 24 hours.

Does this mean my service must be an IPC service?

How can I end my activity and leave the service running?
Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 1):

First off you want to make your service a foreground service.

Something along the lines of this. (I'd call this code in your services onCreate function.)

```
    Notification notification = new Notification(
            R.drawable.ic_dialog_info,
            getText(R.string.notification_text),
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, YourMainClass.class);
    activityIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    activityIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            activityIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
            getText(R.string.notification_title),
            getText(R.string.notification_text), pendingIntent);
    startForeground(123, notification);
```

Another thing is to not bind your service to your activity. If your activity get's killed you don't want your service to die as well. And if your device get's low on memory, if your activity isn't in the foreground it is a candidate for getting killed.  Of course, when memory frees up Android will try to recreate it. But you will have a poor user experience. If your service is not bound to your activity and is foreground, it should be the last thing that gets killed by the OS during garbage collection.

You can start a service without binding it to your activity by using this simple piece of code: This code can be called in your activities onCreate.

```
Intent service = new Intent(YourContext, YourService.class);
startService(service);
```

Hopefully this helps you!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that my app should consist of an activity and a service that the activity binds to.

Not necessarily. You can use the command pattern for this.

> Does this mean my service must be an IPC service?

Not necessarily. You can use the command pattern for this.

> How can I end my activity and leave the service running?

Start the service using `startService()`. Whether it will live for 24 hours is not under your control (see Dyarish's answer for making it be a foreground service, which increases the odds that it will live that long).

Comment: I just went thru "DownloadItYourselfDemo."  My service has to pass a lot of data structures to my activity (if it's running) and the activity has to send some data, now and then, to the service.  I'm wondering if/how this is best done using this pattern.

Comment: @user1058647: That is impossible to answer in the abstract, because "a lot of data structures" is vague. Generally speaking, an activity passes data to a service via extras and such on the `Intent`s supplied to `startService()` calls. A service can send data to an activity via a number of mechanisms outlined in the book (e.g., regular broadcast, `LocalBroadcastManager`, `Messenger`). Whether "the data" is "a lot of data structures" directly, or whether "a lot of data structures" really should be a centralized data model, I cannot say given the information you have supplied.

Comment: CommonsWare: Maybe this is less abstract - the activity starts/stops the service and passes a few simple parameters.  The service is running locationListener and passing Locations (lots of them) up to the activity (if it's running) and is making POSTs to an asp.net web api service on my cloud server.  I'm thinking the pattern in DownloadItYourself is the one to go with.

Comment: @user1058647: Since `Location` is `Parcelable`, it is fairly easy to send that via extras on a broadcast `Intent` (whether a regular broadcast or via `LocalBroadcastManager`), or via the `Bundle` associated with a `Message` for use with a `Messenger`. However, if those `Location`s should be around and usable even if the activity is gone (e.g., user pressed BACK) and the user later returns to it, focus on putting those `Location`s in a centralized data model from which the activity can pull, using a broadcast or something as a "hey! updates ready!" ping.